# Problems with .Net Core SignalR's HubConnectionBuilder in Tizen

Tags: .net-core, xamarin.forms, signalr, tizen, signalr.client

I am developping a Xamarin.Forms app that should be compatible with Windows(UWP), Android and TizenTV. I am using .Net Core SignalR Client. The App works fine on Windows & Android but I can't get it to Work on Tizen (main Code is the same). Especially one line of code from signalR is not Working.

```cs
hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(apiUrl+ "registration-hub").Build();
```

If it is excecuted in an Emulator with the Visual Studio Debugger the code just leaves the thread and doesn't continue after this line.
It doesn't log errors or anything else. If try to change the Exception Settings in Visual Studio i get this notification:

```
This debug engine does not support exception conditions. The condition(s) will be ignored.
```

I tried updating & downgrading packages but nothing worked. I can reproduce this in new empty .Net Tizen Projects.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had exactly the same problem on my Xamarin forms project. For me, the fix was:

- Start debugging
- "Exception Settings" window
- Click 5th icon: "Restore the list fo the default settings"

[image: Restore Default Exception Settings]

Comment: thanks for your response, unfortunetly this doesn't change anything.
Code after `hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(apiUrl+ "registration-hub").Build();` is still not executed and the message about the ignored exception Settings still shows up.